# declaration of variable in teradata

Tags: teradata

Is there an equivalent of declaring a variable similar to this Sql Server (TSQL) code in teradata's sql dialect?

```
DECLARE @Somedate Date = GETUTCDATE();

SELECT TOP 10 * FROM SOMETABLE WHERE SOMEDATE = @Somedate;
```

Comment: How are you executing your query? SQL Assistant, BTEQ?

Comment: You can't use variables outside of a Stored Procedure (or Macro) in Teradata.

Comment: Well, it kind of depends on what the OP means by variables, or is actually trying to do.  You can use ? in SQL Assistant, for BTEQ you can use shell scripts to plug a variable in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.  You cannot declare variables in a typical SQL Statement that you are running directly from your code editor.  You can (as one example) declare variables inside of a stored procedure. In your code editor window, you would be more likely to create a volatile table and use it to store the value of your "variable".

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to just use the following syntax on Teradata? The `Current_Date` part can be replaced with any scalar query. This will work with Teradata SQL Assistant / BTEQ tool

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM SOMETABLE WHERE SOMEDATE = Current_Date;
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM SOMETABLE WHERE SOMEDATE = (SELECT MAX(SameDate) FROM SomeOtherTable);
```

One way to achieve this with date stored as some variable in stored procedures on Teradata is:

```
DECLARE v_SQL_Text VARCHAR(32000);
DECLARE v_Somedate Date;

SELECT Current_Date INTO :v_Somedate;

SET v_SQL_Text = 'SELECT TOP 10 * FROM SOMETABLE WHERE SOMEDATE = ' || v_Somedate || ';'

CALL DBC.SysExecSQL(v_SQL_Text);
```

Comment: Can you please explain how doesn't it work? What tool are you using for querying?

Comment: It isn't a rights issue.  Put it inside a stored proc and it would work (even if run under the same account/permissions).  It just isn't valid syntax in a vanilla SQL Assistant script.

Comment: Okay, I added some text to add clarification of where each of the mentioned solutions.