# Teradata declaring dates at start of the script

Tags: teradata, declare

This may seem like a very basic question.

I have a very large SQL statement with lots of sub queries that contain date limits in multiple where clauses

We run this query on an ad-hoc basis where i have to change the date range in the query in about 20 places. The date range is the same in all the places. So for example 1-Jan-2016 to 7-Jan-2016 as an example

In Teradata is it possible to declare the date range at the start of the query for example like a variable and then reference this variable in the code so i only need to change it once?

I have seen the answer  for [declaration of variable in teradata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39697044/declaration-of-variable-in-teradata) but would like to see a simple example demonstrating the concept for a date range in a stored procedure

Thank you for your time

Comment: The trick to learning some of this stuff about teradata is that you will not always find good answers for the basic stuff with an internet search.  There is some good pdf documentation but it typically doesn't come up in a web search.  You may want to look at downloading some of the pdf documentation from http://info.teradata.com/

Comment: Are you using Teradata SQL Assistant to launch the query "manually"? In this case variable placeholder (e.g: `?startdate, ?enddate`) could be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making it a variable, it should probably be a parameter.  Your stored proc would be something like this:

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE MyStoredProcedure
(
IN StartDate DATE
,IN EndDate DATE
) 
BEGIN
DECLARE SomeOtherDate DATE; --if you need an actual date variable
--Your logic goes here

END;
```

Then you would set the parameters when you call the stored proc

```
CALL MyStoredProcedure('2015-01-01','2015-12-31');
```

Comment: Thank you very much David for your help